# Component will not wait for API response before rendering

Tags: reactjs

I have tried conditional rendering with a flag set after the API call and also using componentDidMount but cannot get this component to wait for an API response before rendering. I know the API response is valid because it is logging ok in the console. I'm new to react, could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? I have looked at the similar questions on Stackoverflow and can't find a fix. Many thanks!

I have cut some methods out of the code snippet to make it more readable.

```
import { OTSession, OTPublisher, OTStreams, OTSubscriber } from 'opentok-react';

import {
  SAMPLE_SERVER_BASE_URL,
} from './config';

export default class CallPane extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      error: null,
      connection: 'Connecting',
      publishVideo: true,
      apiKey: '',
      sessionId: '',
      token: '',
      isLoaded: false,
    };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(SAMPLE_SERVER_BASE_URL + '/session')
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        this.setState({ apiKey: data.apiKey })
        console.log(data.apiKey)
        this.setState({ sessionId: data.sessionId })
        console.log(data.sessionId)
        this.setState({ token: data.token })
        console.log(data.token)
        this.setState({ isLoaded: true })
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error('Failed to get session credentials', err);
        alert('Failed to get opentok sessionId and token. Make sure you have updated the config.js file.');
      });
  }

  render() {

    const { error, connection, publishVideo } = this.state;
    // const { apiKey, sessionId, token } = this.state;

    return (
      // (isLoaded) 
      <div>
        <div id="sessionStatus">Session Status: {connection}</div>
        {error ? (
          <div className="error">
            <strong>Error:</strong> {error}
          </div>
        ) : null}
        <OTSession
          apiKey={this.apiKey}
          sessionId={this.sessionId}
          token={this.token}
          onError={this.onSessionError}
          eventHandlers={this.sessionEventHandlers}
        >
          <button id="videoButton" onClick={this.toggleVideo}>
            {publishVideo ? 'Disable' : 'Enable'} Video
          </button>
          <OTPublisher
            properties={{ publishVideo, width: 250, height: 250, }}
            onPublish={this.onPublish}
            onError={this.onPublishError}
            eventHandlers={this.publisherEventHandlers}
          />
          <OTStreams>
            <OTSubscriber
              properties={{ width: 300, height: 300 }}
              onSubscribe={this.onSubscribe}
              onError={this.onSubscribeError}
              eventHandlers={this.subscriberEventHandlers}
            />
          </OTStreams>
        </OTSession>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! For one, note that you can set more than one state variable at once, by including multiple properties in the object you pass to setState. But more importantly, where do you use isLoaded? You set it, but have the line where I think you want to use it commented out. Assuming that was just to test things, check out https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html, but especially https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator, and check the difference between your `error` conditional and your `isLoaded` conditional.

Comment: Awesome - good point with the setState object. Thanks @HammerN'Songs. Reading the docs now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple if statement, where you check, if the resource is ready yet. If not, render a loading bar or something similar. From the [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#fetching-external-data):

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      externalData: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(SAMPLE_SERVER_BASE_URL + '/session')
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ externalData: data });
      });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.externalData === null) {
      // Render loading state ...
    } else {
      // Render real UI ...
    }
  }
}
```

You could also use something like the following, to make sure that another component is always rendered.

```
class ExampleComponent extends  React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      externalData: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(SAMPLE_SERVER_BASE_URL + '/session')
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ externalData: data });
      });
  }

  //This render is begin called even before props getting updated
  render() {
      return (
          <div>
          <h1>{'This will always render yay '}</h1>
          { this.state && this.state.externalData &&
              <div>{'This will just render after the return of the async call'}</div>
          }
          </div>
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank @Tom Scholz,  the component is rendering properly now! For some reason the props from the aren't passing down as to the OTSession component and I'm getting 'ReferenceError: OT is not defined'. Could this be something to do with the state as the API response is valid and can log it correctly inside the same scope as the render function. I can't seem to add multi line code in this comment.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or a codesandbox to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Got it sorted now thank you - was my fault, just the way I was trying to access the properties!

Answer (score 1):

you can put if statement inside your render method:

```
render() {

    const { error, connection, publishVideo, isLoaded } = this.state;
    // const { apiKey, sessionId, token } = this.state;

    if(!isLoaded) {
      // not loaded
      return (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      )
    }

    return (
      // (isLoaded) 
      // your code
    );
  }
```